# How to locate elements which has same class name for all records?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

how to locate elements for icons(in this case to display the extent within the map)whose id is unknown and no text value also.Those icons on Search panel has got their static class name instead.
I tried to implement both CssSelector and XPath. For some reason CssSelector is not able to find the element, but XPath shows some results partially. I think I will use XPath going forward.

Classname prefix has got to be same for all icons available on that panel.Say,

1. ux-row-action-item hasGeoExt (classname - to display extent within the map)
2. ux-row-action-item m31 (classname - to show metadata)

Since these are splitted by space ,I've implemented code in such a way that the driver would find an element by Xpath fetching its unique classname(Finds elements based on the value of the "class" attribute. If an element has many classes then this will match against each of them.)
In this case,it would take hasGeoExt from (1) and m31 from (2)

Issues I faced in this scenario ,
selecting nth extent/metadata/wms/link icons when the classname is same for all the records.

Comment: Post sample HTML/XML markup plus what you expect the XPath to return given that sample. That will make your requirement easily understood

Comment: you are trying to fetch all values of point 1 and comparing it with list obtained for point 2 ?
Additionally, when it comes to map features the nth index will not be same always because features will be loading randomly as fetched from service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all elements containing the class name `ux-row-action-item`:

```
var icons = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("[class*='ux-row-action-item']"));
```

or

```
var icons = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("*[contains(@class,'ux-row-action-item')]"));
```

To parse the other class names in these elements:

```
foreach(IWebElement singleIcon in icons)
{
    string[] classNames = singleIcon.GetAttribute("class").Split(' ');
}
```